# $("span").each() not working when I do .css() on iterated element

Tags: jquery, css, each

I have a code, where I iterate through elements and I want to get each element css styling.
And I get this error referring to .each:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Here is the example code:

```
  $("span").each(function(i,v){
   test($(this));
 })

 function test(element){
  console.log(element.css());  //not working
  console.log($(element).css()); //not working either
 }
```

Comment: I did. I just wanted to get all styles, when I don't know all possible rules

Answer (score 3):

`.css` *requires* an argument: either pass a single argument, a property name, to retrieve its value, or pass two arguments, a property name and the value to set it to:

```js
$("span").each(function(i, v) {
  test($(this));
})

function test(element) {
  console.log(element.css('color'));
}


$("span").each(function(i, v) {
  test2($(this));
})

function test2(element) {
  element.css('color', 'yellow')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: green">text</span>
```

```js
$("span").each(function(i, v) {
  test($(this));
})

function test(element) {
  console.log(element.css()); //not working
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

If you pass it *no* arguments, jQuery will throw an error, because it's expecting the first argument to be a string.

If you want to access the underlying CSSStyleDeclaration with all properties, use the vanilla DOM methods instead of jQuery:

```js
$("span").each(function(i, v) {
  console.log(this.style);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: green">text</span>
```